# Hiding Columns in Excel Workbooks using openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to hide columns in an Excel workbook I'm creating using the `openxlsx` package in R, but I'm not having any luck. I could make a pre-formatted Excel workbook and write data to it, but the number of columns that need to be hidden is variable. I've tried using:

```
 setColWidths(wb, sheet = "Sheet 1", cols = col_list, widths = 0)
```

where "col_list" is the list of columns that need to be hidden. When I open the saved workbook, the column widths are actually 0.38. If anybody has any ideas on how I might go about this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think if you tried to modify an excel workbook with R, it woudl make more sense for me to use VBA instead..

Comment: That's the thing though. I'm not actually modifying an existing Excel workbook. I'm creating one in R because all of the data that is being written to it is being processed in R, and thus the formatting for the workbook has to be dynamic.

Comment: Looking at the `openxlsx` doc it seems not possible, but you can put you're hidden column in another sheet, and you can hide this sheet using `sheetVisibility(wb)`..

Answer (score 8):

The documentation shows the fields for the formula as below:

```
setColWidths(wb, sheet, cols, widths = 8.43, hidden = rep(FALSE, length(cols)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)
```

So setting `hidden = rep(TRUE, length(cols))` should hide your columns

Comment: @arun Vinoth, what about rows? How to hide rows?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an accidental backdoor by using `NA`

```
setColWidths(wb, sheet = "Sheet 1", cols = col_list, widths = NA)
```

Comment: Hi Fevertree, thanks for answering. Just for the sake of precision, 'backdoor' is generally used to describe a security vulnerability. Are you instead referring to an undocumented function behaviour? A little bit more detail might be helpful here

Comment: Brilliant! "Backdoor" or "Undocumented" - it works!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation shows `groupColumns()` has an option for hidden. It worked better for me.

The man page notes that it conflicts with the parameter in `setColWidths()`. (I think conflicts with is too strong. It's just duplicate).

https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/groupColumns.html

To @Sean in comments, you can hide rows with `groupRows(hidden = TRUE)`.

`groupRows(wb, sheet = "Sheet 1", rows = 6:12, hidden = TRUE)`